# Bash script with global variable

Tags: bash, shell

I execute a bash script with following command:

```
./testscript &
```

It includes:

```
#!/bin/bash
export testvar=OK
...
```

How can I access testvar from another bash script?

Answer (score 2):

You need to source in `testscript` into another script for that using:

```
source ./testscript
```

OR else:

```
. ./testscript
```

That way you avoid creating a sub shell while executing `./testscript` hence variable created remain in scope.